# API Instagram obter informações sobre uma determinada publicação

Tags: php, html, json, api, instagram-api

É possível ter acesso às mídias (claro que públicas) sem ter a autorização do usuário responsável por ela? A ideia é saber o número de curtidas e comentários de uma determinada publicação via API.

Uma das alternativas que encontrei em alguns posts é carregar o html da publicação exemplo: https://www.instagram.com/p/tsxp1hhQTG/ E manualmente buscar o número de curtidas e comentários. Essa alternativa até resolveria o meu problema, porém estou implantando essa solução em um sistema onde vários usuários fariam essa requisição, que talvez seja um tanto quanto "estressante" para o servidor e correria o risco de desconfiarem de DDoS.

Já criei uma "Aplicação Cliente" no Instagram, possuo o Client ID, Client Secret e o ACCESS TOKEN.

Comment: Você quer obter as mídias através de quê? Hashtag? Por usuário?

Comment: @Randrade por media-id ou shortcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Instagram agora está com o modo seguro ([SandBox Mode](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/)).

Esse modo começou a ser implantados para todos os clientes no dia 01 de junho de 2016.

Antes dele, você conseguia obter imagens públicas através de consultas com seu `access_token`, agora isso não é mais possível.
Para obter esses dados utlizando o `access_token`, sua aplicação deve ser submetida ao Instagram para sair do modo SandBox e ir par ao modo online.

### Mas então, o que é **SandBox Mode**?

Cada novo aplicativo criado na plataforma Instagram inicia no modo Sandbox. Este é um ambiente totalmente funcional que permite que você teste terminais de API publicamente disponíveis antes de enviar seu aplicativo para revisão. O modo seguro é ideal para desenvolvedores que são novos para a plataforma Instagram e querem explorar a plataforma API, bem como para as equipes que precisam de vários clientes para o desenvolvimento, teste e outros ambientes não-vivos.

Para ajudá-lo a desenvolver e testar seu aplicativo, os usuários e os meios disponíveis no modo Sandbox são dados reais Instagram (ou seja, o que é normalmente visível no aplicativo Instagram), mas com as seguintes condições:

- Apps na caixa de areia são restritas a 10 usuários
- Os dados são restritas para os utilizadores 10 e 20 os meios mais
  recentes a partir de cada um desses utilizadores
- API reduzidos [limites de taxa](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/)

### O que isso interfere para mim?

Isso é simples meu caro amigo.

Enquanto seu aplicativo estiver no **SandBox Mode**, você só conseguirá interagir com quem estiver configurado junto com você. Ou seja, não terá acesso as fotos e demais informações dos restantes dos usuários.

### Existe outra forma de obter os dados?

Você pode baixar o HTML, como dito da pergunta. Mas o Instagram pode te bloquear com isso. Mas a melhor forma é realmente submeter seu aplicativo para a aprovação.

[Explicação no SOen.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33887790/4843158)

Comment: Então se o Instagram aprovar minha aplicação, isso significa que poderei ter acesso as midias (likes, comentarios, etc) sem necessitar da autorização do usuário?

Comment: @LeonardoRocha Você conseguirá ter acesso as coisas públicas. Para ter acesso as coisas do usuário, ele ainda precisa ser autenticado

Comment: Todas as postagens são públicas?
Se um usuário for público, para que eu possa obter o número de seguidores, ainda sim preciso da autenticação dele?

Comment: @LeonardoRocha Infelizmente sim. Eu odiei essa modificação, mas traz mais segurança para os usuários, e com isso, muito menos requisições para a API do Instagram.

Comment: Mas você tendo seu App publicado, você possui diversas informações, como mostra a documentação